# Multiselect recyclerview

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, multi-select

I want to achieve multiselect in recyclerview. I have almost got it but it behaves weirdly at times or when there are many items.

I would like to have multiselect function where in on selection I want to change the background color of the item and revert the textcolor of all the text views inside it.

I am facing a weird issue, if I select the 1st record and scroll down then even the 8th record gets selected automatically. And if I select 2nd record then 9th one also gets selected.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Models.ViewModels;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace A.Droid.Adapters
{
    public class DeliveryAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter//, View.IOnClickListener
    {
        List<RequestViewModel> list;
        public Context v;
        public event EventHandler<int> phoneClick;

        List<RequestViewModel> selectedList = new List<RequestViewModel>();

        public DeliveryAdapter(List<RequestViewModel> records, Context v1)
        {
            list = records;
            v = v1;
        }
        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            // Inflate the CardView for the photo:
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.activity_cardview_slinkyRecordList, parent, false);

            DeliveryListViewHolder vh = new DeliveryListViewHolder(itemView, OnPhoneClick);
            return vh;
        }

        // Fill in the contents of the photo card (invoked by the layout manager):
        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            DeliveryListViewHolder viewHolder = holder as DeliveryListViewHolder;
            viewHolder.PICNumber.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[position].PICNumber) ? "-" : list[position].PICNumber;
            viewHolder.PropertyName.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[position].PropertyName) ? "-" : list[position].PropertyName;
            viewHolder.ContactAddress.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[position].ContactAddress) ? "-" : list[position].ContactAddress;
            viewHolder.ContactPerson.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[position].ContactPerson) ? "-" : list[position].ContactPerson;
            viewHolder.ContactNumber.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[position].ContactNumber) ? "-" : list[position].ContactNumber;

            viewHolder.NumberOfAliveSpecies.Text = list[position].NumberOfAliveStock + " Alive " + list[position].NameOfSpecies;
            viewHolder.NumberOfDeadSpecies.Text = list[position].NumberOfDeadStock + " Dead " + list[position].NameOfSpecies;

            viewHolder.DistanceOfTransporterToPIC.Text = list[position].DistanceOfTransporterFromPIC.ToString() + " KM"; //DeliveryList[position].DistanceOfTransporterFromPIC.ToString();
                                                                                                                         //viewHolder.MainLinearLayout.SetOnClickListener((new OnClickListener(viewHolder.MainLinearLayout,position));                                                                         // cardViewList.Add(viewHolder.cardView); //add all the cards to this list
                                                                                                                         //viewHolder.MainLinearLayout.SetOnClickListener(this);                                                                        // cardViewList.Add(viewHolder.cardView); //add all the cards to this list

            viewHolder.cardView.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (selectedList.All(i => i.slinkyStockRequestId != list[position].slinkyStockRequestId))
                {
                    selectedList.Add(list[position]);

                    viewHolder.MainLinearLayout.SetBackgroundColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));

                    viewHolder.PICNumber.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));
                    viewHolder.PropertyName.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));
                    viewHolder.ContactAddress.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));
                    viewHolder.ContactPerson.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));
                    viewHolder.ContactNumber.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));

                    viewHolder.NumberOfAliveSpecies.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));
                    viewHolder.NumberOfDeadSpecies.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));

                    viewHolder.DistanceOfTransporterToPIC.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));
                    viewHolder.mapIcon.SetColorFilter(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
                    viewHolder.contactIcon.SetColorFilter(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
                    viewHolder.phoneIcon.SetColorFilter(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);

                }
                else
                {
                    selectedList.Remove(list[position]);

                    viewHolder.MainLinearLayout.SetBackgroundColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.dark_blue));

                    viewHolder.PICNumber.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));
                    viewHolder.PropertyName.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));
                    viewHolder.ContactAddress.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));
                    viewHolder.ContactPerson.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));
                    viewHolder.ContactNumber.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));

                    viewHolder.NumberOfAliveSpecies.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));
                    viewHolder.NumberOfDeadSpecies.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));

                    viewHolder.DistanceOfTransporterToPIC.SetTextColor(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white));
                    viewHolder.mapIcon.SetColorFilter(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
                    viewHolder.contactIcon.SetColorFilter(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
                    viewHolder.phoneIcon.SetColorFilter(v.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);

                }
            };



            animate(holder);
        }


        public List<RequestViewModel> GetSelectedItems()
        {
            return selectedList;
        }


        // Return the number of photos available in the photo album:
        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return list.Count; }
        }


        // Raise an event when the phone-click takes place:
        void OnPhoneClick(int position)
        {
            if (phoneClick != null)
            {
                phoneClick(this, position);
            }
        }


        public class DeliveryListViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public ImageView MapTag { get; private set; }
            public TextView PICNumber { get; private set; }
            public TextView PropertyName { get; private set; }
            public TextView ContactAddress { get; private set; }
            public TextView ContactPerson { get; private set; }
            public TextView ContactNumber { get; private set; }
            public TextView NameOfSpecies { get; private set; }
            public TextView NumberOfAliveSpecies { get; private set; }
            public TextView NumberOfDeadSpecies { get; private set; }
            public TextView DistanceOfTransporterToPIC { get; private set; }
            public CardView cardView { get; private set; }
            public LinearLayout MainLinearLayout { get; private set; }
            public ImageView mapIcon { get; private set; }
            public ImageView contactIcon { get; private set; }
            public ImageView phoneIcon { get; private set; }
            // Get references to the views defined in the CardView layout.
            public DeliveryListViewHolder(View itemView, Action<int> phoneClickListener) : base(itemView)
            {
                MapTag = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.mapIcon);
                PICNumber = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.PICNumber);
                PropertyName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nameOfProperty);
                ContactPerson = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.contactPerson);
                NumberOfAliveSpecies = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.noOfAliveSpecies);
                NumberOfDeadSpecies = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.noOfDeadSpecies);
                DistanceOfTransporterToPIC = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.areaInKM);
                ContactAddress = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.address);
                ContactNumber = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.mobileNo);
                mapIcon = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.mapIcon);
                contactIcon = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.contactIcon);
                phoneIcon = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.phoneIcon);

                cardView = itemView.FindViewById<CardView>(Resource.Id.mainCardviewLayout);
                MainLinearLayout = itemView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.MainLinearLayout);
                ContactNumber.Click += (sender, e) => phoneClickListener(base.Position);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: For Kotlin users, the following article might be useful [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Your Model should have**

```
private boolean isSelected = false

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }
```

> **in your onClick event,**

Note: For Best practice setTag(position) with your position to your view that is getting clicked and use that tag value as a position.

```
int pos = (int) view.getTag(); 
list[pos].setSelected(!list[pos].isSelected());
                        notifyItemChanged(position);
```

**I think this will resolve your problem regarding**

*I select the 1st record and scroll down then even the 8th record gets selected automatically. And if I select 2nd record then 9th one also gets selected.*

> Once you will use and operate using position with setTag() this issue of scrolling and position getting selected automatically will be eliminated

Answer (score 0):

Add one extra field in your model class

`public boolean isSelected = false;`

then after in `bindViewHolder` manage your check/uncheck view.

if the user clicks on your particular view you have to manage like below code.

```
list.get(position).setSelected(true);
notifyItemChanged(position);
```

Here, `setSelected()` is a method from your model class.

Comment: Could you please explain how to use setselected

Comment: See when you will add boolean variable named isSelected then after generate getter and setter method and then you will get setSelected().

Comment: I am using xamarin android. I am finding it difficult to understand what you mean. Can you give me an example of how it is done?

Comment: I even tried removing the click functionality from bindViewHolder as it gets called multiple time. I added click method in my activity but still same behaviour.